# Transfer function estimation of a noisy system

Tags: transfer-function, estimation

## Overall description

I am trying to estimate a filtering system’s transfer function, given its input and output.
This system takes $x$ as input . This signal is low pass filtered and added to a WGN by the system, which gives the output signal $y$.

\begin{align}
x &= \text{BPSK} + b_1 \\
y &= h*x + b_2 \text,
\end{align}

$b_1$ and $b_2$ being white gaussian Noise

### Hypothesis

- $b_1\ll b_2 \ll x$
- $b_1, b_2$ independent

[image]

The purpose of my manipulation is to estimate as best as possible the filter’s frequency response amplitude ($|H|$) and compare it with the applied filtering (which is known – red plot on next figures).

I had some trouble with this task and it would be very helpful if someone could help with an additional signal conditioning or identify an algorithmic issue.

## Algorithm

Theoretically, a simple estimator based on PSD (Power Spectral Density) of input and output signals can be performed with following equations:

$$H(\omega) = \frac{S_{xy}(\omega)}{S_x(\omega)}$$

with $S_{xy}(\omega) = \text{FFT}\left(R_{xy}(\tau)\right) = \text{FFT}(\mathtt{xcorr}(x,y))$ and $S_{x}(\omega) = \text{FFT}\left(R_{x}(\tau)\right) = \text{FFT}(\mathtt{xcorr}(x))$.

For a better signal to noise ratio, the signals ($x$ and $y$)  are split into bursts to compute a mean FFT.

## Results

The output of this estimator is also given hereafter (Estimated TF = estimated transfer function). It can be seen that the estimator is noisy.

[image]

In this step I have tried to enhance the estimator by adding median filter on the transfer function estimate. However, this did not improve the estimator.

[image]

It seems that the Frequency response amplitude estimate shows  spectral hollows compared to the input filtering, which are inducing an important error on the estimate.

## Questions

- What kind of filter (or another way to estimate the transfer function) can I use?
- Could a signal conditioning on $x$ or $y$ enhance the
  estimator accuracy?

The following Matlab function is used to compute the TF estimation. Please note that nb_means parameter is arbitrary equal to 16 in my computation, this parameter can evolve.

```
function [ H1, G1 ] = estimateTF_DSP( sigX, sigY, nb_means )
if nb_means > 1
    sigX_I_reshaped = reshape(real(sigX),length(real(sigX))/nb_means,nb_means)';
    sigX_Q_reshaped = reshape(imag(sigX),length(imag(sigX))/nb_means,nb_means)';
    sigY_I_reshaped = reshape(real(sigY),length(real(sigY))/nb_means,nb_means)';
    sigY_Q_reshaped = reshape(imag(sigY),length(imag(sigY))/nb_means,nb_means)';     
    
    for k=1:size(sigX_I_reshaped,1);
        sig_X = sigX_I_reshaped(k,:)+1i*sigX_Q_reshaped(k,:);
        sig_Y = sigY_I_reshaped(k,:)+1i*sigY_Q_reshaped(k,:);
        % XY
        Rxy = xcorr(sig_X,sig_Y);
        Sxy(k,:) = fft(Rxy);
        % X
        Rx = xcorr(sig_X);
        Sx(k,:) = fft(Rx);        
    end
    
    Sx_m = mean(Sx);
    Sxy_m = mean(Sxy);
    
else    
    % XY
    Rxy = xcorr(sigX,sigY);
    Sxy_m = fft(Rxy);
    % X
    Rx = xcorr(sigX);
    Sx_m = fft(Rx);
end

H1 = (Sxy_m./Sx_m)./(2*pi);
G1 = 20*log10(abs(H1));
end
```

Comment: Hi Math! Your notation is a bit strange at times; what's BPSK(1)? When you write $H(x)$, do you mean $h*x$ or do you mean $H(\omega = x)$? You might want to write something like $E(|b_1|)\ll E(|b_2|)$, because for WGN, $b_1 \ll b_2$ cannot be true in general.

Comment: And: this is a nice post! But, you forgot to actually **ask a question**. Make it as precise as possible without being overspecific, please.

Comment: Hi Marcus ! Thanks for your remarks ! 
So, here are my answers :

 - BPSK(1) stands for basically BPSK signal

 - In fact, H(x) stands for h*x

 - You're right about WGN, thanks !


Finally, I forgot to paste the essential part of my question... So I have edited my post with your remarks ! 
Thanks again @MarcusMüller!

Comment: Can't you just use the [tfestimate](https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tfestimate.html) function?

Comment: I already tried this function, but with no satisfying results. 
My estimator seems accurate for signals with equal C/N0 (different noise draw are not affecting results). With different C/N0, the resulting estimation is really noisy...